# Radio - Amplifier Connection

Tags: analog, audio, radio, automotive, reverse-engineering

This is my first post here, so please give me feedback on how I can improve in the future.

### Background

I am trying to reverse engineer a Becker Grand Prix Stereo Radio with an external amplifier.

On the back of the Radio, there is a 7-pin DIN connected with some pins jumped using a factory plug. Pin 4 is connected to pin 5, and pin 1 is connected to pin 3. Basically the plug is jumping these pins so that the output is connected to the amplifier.

The diagram is supposed to for wiring an aux jack to the radio.

#### Pinout in English

1. Radio Out Right Channel
2. Car chassis ground
3. Amplifier input Right channel
4. Radio Out Left Channel
5. Amplifier input Left Channel
6. Audio Ground
7. On/Off Switch.

[image: aux wiring diagram]
[image: no resistor diagram].

### Question

What I'm trying to understand is the purpose of the 4.7k Ohm resistors on diagram 1?
Are these used to reduce the current of the aux (line) signal?

Some diagrams have it, others omit it.

Please let me know if I need to clarify.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm guessing it prevents damage to the radio and/or CD/MP3 player caused by connecting their outputs together. But if the radio were operating it would drown out the CD/MP3 player. Use the bottom right diagram instead as that disconnects the radio when you plug a device into the jack socket.

Comment: *Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.* - you might be on the wrong site here.

Comment: The upper right diagram, which uses resistors and terminates in a plug, is not as good an approach. The resistors prevent potential damage caused by connecting two outputs together.  The lower right diagram, which terminates in a jack with internal switches, is the best way to go. No resistors are needed because, for each stereo channel, only one output is connected at a time to the amplifier input.

Comment: I believe that the diagram with the resistors directly to the plug is intended as an AUX OUT only. This setup would be used if you wanted to add a few more speakers utilizing an external amplifier while still having the standard speakers connected to the internal amplifier. You must use the switched jack scheme if you want to use it as an input.